# how to cache ajax requests and responses & stop to duplicate ajax request

Tags: php, jquery

how to cache ajax requests and responses & stop to duplicate ajax request ?
there are any way to store all ajax request and response on client cache.avoid making repeated request.

advance thanks

Comment: The question you ask is a little vague without context. Do you want it to stay cached during a user's session? or is it for the general public? is there a timeout associated? Is it specific to a user? jquery.ajax already supports [cache](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: i want to use this fundamental for my search box.when ever type in input box if keyword is repeated so no ajax request fire...data retrieved from cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({

cache:true,
.
.
.
});
```

You should create a key for each request and check request key before send to filter duplicate requests!